# Symfony2 - extending existing non-abstract entity?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Let's say I have a `Setting` entity with some fields like `IntValue`, `dateValue`, `stringValue` and some linked entities, like `countries (ManyToMany to entity Country)`, `languages (ManyToMany to Language)` etc.

Settings are created by users and assigned to specific objects (not important here, but I wanted to clarify).

Now I suddenly need to have `UserDefaultSetting`, which will be the same, but with additional `user` field (ManyToOne to `User` entity).

I tried to extend existing `Setting` entity class with one more field added. The problem is, as I looked at the schema update SQL, it created new table for the new entity, but without all the tables needed to ORM connections (mostly ManyToMany). Just one table with "scalar" fields.

So previously I've had `setting` table with `int_value`, `date_value` etc. but also `setting_country` and `setting_language` tables, linking ManyToMany relations. After creating child entity, Doctrine created only `user_default_setting` table with `int_value`, `date_value` etc. and additionally `user_id` column, but I can't see any relation/link tables.

I know I should've been do it with abstract base entity class, but at the time I started, I didn't know that and now part of the project is on production (don't look at me like that, I blame the client) and I don't want to change that "base" class now. Can I inherit everything from non-abstract entity class in a way it will work?

**UPDATE**: everything explained. See Cerad's comment. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show your entities ?

Comment: To do it right you need to use a mapped superclass: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#mapped-superclasses.  But, as I suspect you know, a mapped superclass cannot be an entity.  You could take your existing Setting entity, make it a super class and then just have Setting inherit from it.  In theory, everything should work as before.  But if you really don't want to touch the Setting entity then copy/paste to UserDefaultSetting and go with what you have.

Comment: @Cerad I wish I could mark your comment as answer! I will have to test everything, but seems like I just have to take all the fields from previous entity, put them in `MappedSuperclass` as protected and then just `extend` that one! Additionally I see I am able to extend that `MappedSuperclass` with my `AbstractEntity` containing `Gedmo` timestampables. That's awesome, thanks!